# How to define the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I wonder how to define sum of two random variables properly.

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space and $X,Y\colon \Omega\to  \mathbb{R}$ are random variables. It is most certainly wrong to define $X+Y$ pointwise. This seems to be the common way to do it though. How to do it correctly?

Edit: To see why defining it pointwise is wrong consider rolling a dice. For concreteness assume that $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, that $\mathcal{F}=\wp(\Omega)$ and that P is induced by the map $p\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto 1/6$. Then we may consider the random variables $X,Y\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ both the inclusion map from $\Omega \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We should have $P(X+Y=3)=2/36$, but defining it pointwise yields probability zero.

Comment: Why is it most certainly wrong?

Comment: The only caveat I can think of is that random variables are not quite functions, rather equivalence classes of functions with respect to almost sure equality, so you really have $(X + Y)(\omega) = X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$ for almost every $\omega$.  Or, you might say, any representative of $X+Y$ is almost everywhere the pointwise sum of any representative of $X$ and any representative of $Y$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: when we consider random variables, we do not always fix the measure, so I'd rather say they are quite functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake in your example is in using the wrong probability space.  A member of $\Omega$ is an "outcome" from which you can obtain values of all the random variables you're interested in.  If you want $X$ and $Y$ to be independent random variables, $\Omega$ might be $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$, not $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$; as functions, $X$ and $Y$ are the first and second coordinate projections.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot define "the" sum of two random variables but many like the "independent sum" and the "pointwise sum"?

Comment: The random variables are defined in terms of a certain probability space.  Once you have that, the sum is the pointwise sum.